# Meteor Moving from Collection to SmartCollection Breaking Templates

Tags: meteor, smartcollection

I am using 0.7.0.1 Meteor and am trying to update from Collection to SmartCollection.  See below... the first one works and the second one doesnt (but does when I switch back from SmartCollection to Collection).  The _id works in both cases but not name.  I read somewhere that name might be a reserved word or something, but why would it work in the other first example below?  Any ideas?  What could it be in SmartCollection that is breaking this?

working

```
{{#each operatingSystemBrands}}
        <input type="radio" class="brandRadios" name="brandRadios" id="{{_id}}" value="{{_id}}">
        <label for="{{_id}}">{{name}}</label>
{{/each}}
```

not working:

```
{{#each devices}}
        <input type="radio" class="deviceRadios" name="deviceRadios" id="{{_id}}" value="{{_id}}">
        <label for="{{_id}}">{{name}}</label>
{{/each}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NM, was a separate issue.  Was an issue when I was converting js to coffeescript, not sure why it broke only when going to smartcollections.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a bug, try using `{{this.name}}`, instead. Not sure if it'll help but its just a hunch. The context might be getting messed up.

I know iron-router is doing this. Did you also upgrade it?

Comment: Using "this." didnt work.  My iron-router is 0.6.2 which is up to date. Are you saying maybe try to downgrade it?

Comment: It's crazy... i changed the field "name" to "bob" in case it was a reserved field or something, but it still doesnt work.